# What is the difference between <Switch> and placing 'Exact' before 'path' in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The headline says it all, what is the difference? Both match a unique path and render the component.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `Switch` the execution will look for a single route and return the response as soon as it finds the route.

While using `exact`, and not using `Switch` all routes will be checked. No matter the route is found on the first place or the last. This will be a performance lack. So, using `Switch` is a better option in my opinion.